# IE11 converting .xlsx files to .xls and .docx files to .doc

Tags: java, ms-office, internet-explorer-11

I have a java application where users can upload and download files. Recently, we found out that whenever users click on a link  on IE11 to download .docx or a .xlsx file, it downloads a .doc or .xls file. In the process, it warns the users that the file format and extension do not match and the users should only open the file if they trust its source. There is no such issue on Microsoft Edge or other browsers.
Is there some setting that can be done in IE11 or can some coding (specific to IE11) be done so that so that it downloads .xlsx and .docx files as they are and doesn't give annoying warning messages to users?

```
            try {
            byte[] fileContent = getFileContent(id, fName);
            if (fileContent != null) {
                OutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    System.out.println("content type: "+getContentType(fName)); //prints application/vnd.ms-excel
                    res.reset();
                    out = res.getOutputStream();
                    res.setContentType(getContentType(fName));
                    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fName + "; size=" + String.valueOf(fileContent.length));
                    res.setContentLength(fileContent.length);
                    out.write(fileContent);
                    setDestination(req, RESPONSE_NO_REDIRECT);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    flushCloseOutputStream(out);
                }
            } else {
                setDestination(req, "/404.jsp");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    public byte[] getFileContent(int id, String fileName) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session s = null;
    try {
        GenericDAO dao = HibernateDAOFactory.getInstance().getDAO(GenericClassDAO.class, Files.class);
        s = SessionAndTransactionManagementService.createNewSession(dao);
        tx = SessionAndTransactionManagementService.startNewTransaction(s);
        Criteria cr = s.createCriteria(Files.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("id", id))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("fileName", fileName))
                .setProjection(Projections.property("fileContent"));
        bytes = (byte[]) cr.uniqueResult();
        SessionAndTransactionManagementService.commitTransaction(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        HibernateUtil.rollback(tx);
        
    }finally{
        HibernateUtil.cleanupResources(s);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: The IE browser does not convert the .docx to .doc by itself. Also, there is no setting to fix this issue from the IE side. You need to debug your code to find the cause of the issue. If possible then try to provide any sample code to check for the issue. Try to provide detailed information about the issue. Let us know, which version of the MS Office is installed on your side and which OS build you are using?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Added the code to download the file. I am reading the file contents from a database. There is no error message while downloading the files so unable to debug.

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether this issue can be produced with the IE 11 browser on any machine? or it can only be produced on a specific machine? Did you pass the extension with the file name while calling the function?

Comment: I believe it is happening on all machines. A number of users have reported this issue. File name contains the extension while calling the function.

Comment: I try to check your above-posted code and try to run it on my side. I found that many methods are missing and I not sure what values you had passed for the parameters. Due to this reason, I am not able to run the code. I also noticed that you are setting the `res.setContentType(getContentType(fName));` with file name. I am not sure why you are passing the file name here. If there is any simple way to produce the issue then please inform me. I will again try to check for the issue.

Comment: File name contains file extension and this helps set the content type for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 was setting content type for all excel files as 'application/vnd.ms-excel' (don't know why). That makes it show warnings and download xlsx files as xls.

I changed my code to set contentType manually to 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' when the filename contains .xlsx and this solved my problem.